# After an await call, it doesn't execute next line

Tags: javascript

```
const blabla = async () => {
    const foobar = async () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            console.log("foo");
        })
    }
    await foobar();
    console.log("bar");
}
blabla();
```

What output I expected is

```
foo
bar
```

But what I get only is `foo`, there is no `bar` there as I expected. It seems like `console.log("bar");` doesn't executed.

```
foo
```

Comment: You forgot to call `resolve`, so the Promise hangs forever, unresolved

Comment: Is this in a browser or in node?

Comment: @xdhmoore it doesn't matter, the described behavior (and the correct solution) would apply in both environments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to resolve your Promise.

```js
const blabla = async () => {
    const foobar = async () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            console.log("foo");
            resolve();  // <----- Resolve!
        })
    }
    await foobar();
    console.log("bar");
}
blabla();
```